# Click event doesn't work on ajax generated elements

Tags: jquery

This is related to [Click event doesn't work on dynamically generated elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6658752/click-event-doesnt-work-on-dynamically-generated-elements)

Basically I tried to expand a collapsed blockquote upon click

```
replyfix($('#element'));//In the original data, the expander works as intented 

$.ajax({
    url : pageurl,
    success : function (source) {
        $('#element').after(replyfix($(source).find('#element')));
    }
});

function replyfix(reply){
    reply.find('blockquote blockquote').addClass('collapsed').append('<a href="javascript:;" class="expander">click</a>').children('div').hide();
    reply.find('.expander').one('click', function(){
        $(this).parent().find('div').show();
        $(this).parent().find('.expander').remove();
    });
    return reply;
}
```

My question is that the object should already be created in the ajax request, and that I bind the new data every time they are created. Why would direct binding not work?

At first I thought I did something wrong in my code, so I tried to confirm I binded an event on the newly created object using

```
console.log($._data(reply.find('.expander')[0], "events"));
```

and it shows that the new expander already got an click event binded.

update: 
The above code is what I have used before, that I would like to understand why it won't work.

```
$('#element').on('click', ".expander", function(){
    $(this).parent().find('div').show();
    $(this).parent().find('.expander').remove();
});
```

has already solved the problem.

Comment: Check `after()` doc, your code doesn't make any sense...

Comment: opps, I missed a return.

Comment: `source` does not appear to be a jQuery object at `$('#element').after(replyfix(source));` ? Does `reply.find` return an error at `console` when `replyfix` called ?

Comment: Yet another mistake when I try to remove the unrelated code, sorry.

Comment: When I review the code I find out where the problem is, apparently I used `.after($.parseHTML(replyFix($(this)).wrap('<p/>').parent().html()))` instead of directly `.after(replyFix($(this)))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Direct binding does work as the testing code

```
console.log($._data(reply.find('.expander')[0], "events"));
```

confirms the the binding exists.

In my non-simplified code, I've used the following code to avoid some problem when directly inserting

```
.after($.parseHTML(replyFix($(this)).wrap('<p/>').parent().html()))
```

instead of directly

```
.after(replyFix($(this)))
```

This caused a re-parse on HTML, creating new object, with no binding at all. The test occurs in replyfix, where the re-parse hasn't happened, the binding it shows is lost with the original parsed `replyFix($(this))`.

Answer (score 0):

Use delegate instead. For example.But use need to predefine that before ajax call even if the element is not added yet. Make sure you bind with body like below.

```
$('body').delegate('ajax added element','click',function(e){
   //do something
})
```

Other binding in jquery does not work on ajax generated element. That is where the delegate comes in handy. So try to understand jquery delegate binding first.

Comment: Yes . Thanks you for sharing.

Comment: I have used the .on() with delegate. I want to understand why direct binding doesn't work even when it is already exist when binding, and that logs shows it has an event on it.

Comment: I dont see any delegate in your code. I only see one instead of on . reply.find('.expander').one('click', function(){ --------